# Effect of the pipe diameter in speed of the simulation - Modelica

Tags: modelica

I use Ansys TwinBuilder R2.4 for Modelica simulations. I modeled a hydraulic system in Modelica which can be simulated in certain conditions, e.g. when the diameter of the pipe, which is located before the "Auslass" boundary condition, is 5 mm, when I change it to 8 mm, simulation doesn´t proceed. It slows down the progress of the simulation considerably. What can be reason of the difference in speed of the simulation only if the diameter of the pipe is changed? I added block diagram and the code of the model.

[image: Screenshot of hydraulic system]

```
model HD_3Kolben_bsp
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real N = 2800;
    replaceable package medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater( );
    Real opening_HP;
    Real opening_LP;
    constant Modelica.SIunits.AbsolutePressure patm = 1e5;
    Real opening_HP_2;
    Real opening_LP_2;
    Real opening_HP_3;
    Real opening_LP_3;
    constant Modelica.SIunits.Frequency freq = 46;
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system (p_ambient = 101325);
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 0);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume1 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Swept_CV_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Auslass (p = patm, redeclare package Medium = medium, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile1 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile1 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Ein_ND (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Einlass (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position;
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position2;
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile2 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP_2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile2 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP_2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Swept_CV_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume2 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine2 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 7/(3*freq));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit2 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben2 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position3;
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile3 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP_3);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile3 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP_3);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Swept_CV_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume3 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine3 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 14/(3*freq));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit3 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben3 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1 (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary2 (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe4 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe5 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe6 (
        length = 5,
        diameter = 0.005,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume2 (
        V = 3.13e-6,
        nPorts = 4,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice (diameter = 0.005, zeta = 5, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe7 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.005,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);


equation
    if der(Position.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP=1;  
           opening_HP=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP=0;
           opening_HP=1;
     end if; 
    if der(Position2.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP_2=1;  
           opening_HP_2=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP_2=0;
           opening_HP_2=1;
     end if;
     if der(Position3.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP_3=1;  
           opening_HP_3=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP_3=0;
           opening_HP_3=1;
     end if;
    //Connection(s)
    connect(Posit1.flange, Kolben1.flange);
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_1.port_a, Kolben1.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_1.port_b, HDVentile1.port_a);
    connect(NDVentile1.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_1.port_a);
    connect(Einlass.ports[1], pipe_Ein_ND.port_a);
    connect(Posit1.flange, Position.flange);
    connect(Position2.flange, Posit2.flange);
    connect(NDVentile2.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_2.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile2.port_a, pipe_CV_HD_2.port_b);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_2.port_a, Kolben2.ports[1]);
    connect(Sine2.y, Posit2.s_ref);
    connect(Posit2.flange, Kolben2.flange);
    connect(Position3.flange, Posit3.flange);
    connect(NDVentile3.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile3.port_a, pipe_CV_HD_3.port_b);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_3.port_a, Kolben3.ports[1]);
    connect(Sine3.y, Posit3.s_ref);
    connect(Posit3.flange, Kolben3.flange);
    connect(boundary1.ports[1], pipe1.port_a);
    connect(boundary2.ports[1], pipe2.port_a);
    connect(pipe_Ein_ND.port_b, NDVentile1.port_a);
    connect(pipe1.port_b, NDVentile2.port_a);
    connect(pipe2.port_b, NDVentile3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile1.port_b, pipe3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile2.port_b, pipe4.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile3.port_b, pipe5.port_a);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_1.port_b, ClosedVolume1.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_1.port_b, ClosedVolume1.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_1.port_a, ClosedVolume1.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_2.port_b, ClosedVolume2.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_2.port_b, ClosedVolume2.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_2.port_a, ClosedVolume2.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_3.port_b, ClosedVolume3.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_3.port_b, ClosedVolume3.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_3.port_a, ClosedVolume3.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe3.port_b, volume2.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe4.port_b, volume2.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe5.port_b, volume2.ports[3]);
    connect(volume2.ports[4], pipe6.port_a);
    connect(orifice.port_a, pipe6.port_b);
    connect(orifice.port_b, pipe7.port_a);
    connect(pipe7.port_b, Auslass.ports[1]);
end  HD_3Kolben_bsp;
```

Best regards

Comment: which pressure loss model are you using in the pipes?

Comment: I use modelStructure "ModelStructure.av_vb" and nNodes is 2.

Comment: Which model is used to calculate the pressure drop in the pipe model? Is it the default one in Modelica.Fluid?

Comment: Yes, it is default. I did no change in the model for pressure loss calculation in the dynamic pipe model.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a number of things. From a screenshot it is only possible to give very general advice. As it is "only" a parameter the system's structure shouldn't change. Therefore it is likely related to dynamics of the system. I would take a look at the solver log first, starting with the number of computed steps or the step-size. If that changed in an order of magnitude of the slow-down you experience this is a good starting point.

Another issue could be chattering, which could be judged with knowledge about the number of events that happened. These should also be visible from the solver log.

Some additional information that would help:

- Which Modelica-Tool are you using?
- The model itself (with which all of the below can be generated)
- The solver log (before and after the parameter change)
- The translation log incl. system properties like the sizes of equation systems (before and after the parameter change)

I'm afraid without any additional information you will not get utterly helpful advice...

Comment: I added the informations related the first and second points. I cant generate the solver log. And I couldnt add the system properties via hyperlink.

Comment: With pipe7.diameter = 0.005 (so the setting that should work if I understood you correctly) the simulation fails directly after the simulation in Dymola 2021. In a newer version - after converting to MSL 4.0.0 it complains, that: 
`IF97 medium function tsat called with too low pressure`
`p = -9384.63 Pa <= 611.657 Pa (triple point pressure)`
`Failed condition: p > 611.657`
So it seems this is an issue with the operating point of the medium.

Comment: Thanks, actually I get an error at approximately 180 ms., when pipe7.diameter =0.005. but I don´t have an error immediately.

Comment: It seems strange, because I don`t get such a strange pressure value at any component.

Comment: Can I also see the reason of the error when I simulate the model in TwinBuilder R.2.4? How can the error message be converted to MSL 4.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have used the default flowModel to calculate the pressure drop. This model depends on the pipe diameter (flow regime turbulent/laminar).

For a further detailed answer, I would need the information my colleague asks for in his answer above.